# Pandas: merge data frame but summing overlapping columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've been reading lots of posts about the `merge()` and `join()` methods of `pandas.DataFrames`, and trying these on my own problem but not quite found a solution.

I have a very large data file (.csv) containing the hourly consumption of something for various IDs. I want to aggregate the consumption for each ID over each month.

Due to memory limitations I need to process the hourly consumption file with `read_csv` in chunks (using `chunk_size` option), and end up with a load of DataFrames of consumption for IDs for some months, e.g.:

```
df1 = 
 Month  Dec  Nov
ID             
XXX    4.0  1.0
YYY    8.0  3.0
ZZZ    4.0  1.0 

df2 = 
 Month  Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                  
AAA    1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB    0.0  NaN  2.0
YYY    5.0  5.0  0.0
```

Generated for this post by:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['XXX','XXX','YYY','YYY','ZZZ','ZZZ'], 
                    'Month': ['Nov','Dec']*3, 
                    'Consumption': [1.0,4.0,3.0,8.0,1.0,4.0]})
df1 = df1.pivot(index='ID', columns='Month', values='Consumption')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AAA','AAA','AAA','YYY','YYY','YYY','BBB','BBB','BBB'], 
                    'Month': ['Oct','Nov','Dec']*3, 
                    'Consumption': [9,7,1,0,5,5,2,np.nan,0]})
df2 = df2.pivot(index='ID', columns='Month', values='Consumption')
```

*Note that there is a difference between a consumption of `0.0` and `NaN`. `0.0` means there was at least one consumption reading of `0.0` in the month, but `NaN` means there was no consumption value logged at all and, in this case, 0 cannot be assumed. For my purposes this difference must be kept distinct.*

Because the data file is processed in chunks, there are some IDs that appear in more than one DataFrame, e.g. `YYY`, and, for those IDs, sometimes the months overlap too, e.g. `Nov` for ID `YYY`. In this case, consumption in the first half of the month is in `df1` and the second half is in `df2`.

To aggregate the consumption I therefore need to merge these DataFrames by 'ID' and sum values in overlapping 'Months'.

**Straight summing** the DataFrames yields many NaNs:

```
df1 + df2 = 
 Month   Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                   
AAA     NaN  NaN  NaN
BBB     NaN  NaN  NaN
XXX     NaN  NaN  NaN
YYY    13.0  8.0  NaN
ZZZ     NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I assume this is because when summing IDs/Months of `df1` that don't appear `df2` it returns a NaN.

**Outer merging** produces the suffixed columns for overlapping months:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='ID') = 
 Month  Dec_x  Nov_x  Dec_y  Nov_y  Oct
ID                                    
XXX      4.0    1.0    NaN    NaN  NaN
YYY      8.0    3.0    5.0    5.0  0.0
ZZZ      4.0    1.0    NaN    NaN  NaN
AAA      NaN    NaN    1.0    7.0  9.0
BBB      NaN    NaN    0.0    NaN  2.0
```

I couldn't get `combine_first` to do what I want either.

What I want is something in the middle, that looks like this:

```
 Month   Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                   
XXX      4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY     13.0  8.0  0.0
ZZZ      4.0  1.0  NaN
AAA      1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB      0.0  NaN  2.0
```

**Where overlapping months are summed such that `x + NaN = x`, `NaN + y = y` and `NaN + NaN = NaN`.**

---

One solution I can see to do the merge, then sum the overlapping columns, ignoring NaNs:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='ID',suffixes=['','_x'])
overlapping_months_sufx = df3.columns.values[df3.columns.str.endswith('_x')]
for mnth_sufx in overlapping_months_sufx:
    mnth = mnth_sufx[:-2]
    df3[mnth][df3[mnth_sufx].notnull()] = df3[mnth].fillna(0) + df3[mnth_sufx]
    df3=df3.drop(columns=mnth_sufx)
df3 = 
 Month   Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                   
XXX     4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY    13.0  8.0  0.0
ZZZ     4.0  1.0  NaN
AAA     1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB     0.0  NaN  2.0
```

Given the size of this data set it would be great to have the most efficient way to aggregate all this. Is there a better way to do it, perhaps in a single step?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an attempt. Please leave a comment if I understood correctly.

Given:

```
>>> df1                                                                                                                
Month  Dec  Nov
ID             
XXX    4.0  1.0
YYY    8.0  3.0
ZZZ    4.0  1.0
>>> df2                                                                                                                
Month  Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                  
AAA    1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB    0.0  NaN  2.0
YYY    5.0  5.0  0.0
```

Solution:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().groupby('ID', sort=False).sum(min_count=1)
      Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                 
XXX   4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY  13.0  8.0  0.0
ZZZ   4.0  1.0  NaN
AAA   1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB   0.0  NaN  2.0
```

---

Explanation:

Concatenation just puts `df2` under `df1`.

```
>>> cat = pd.concat([df1, df2])                                                                                        
>>> cat                                                                                                                
     Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                
XXX  4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY  8.0  3.0  NaN
ZZZ  4.0  1.0  NaN
AAA  1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB  0.0  NaN  2.0
YYY  5.0  5.0  0.0
```

`reset_index` moves the index into the columns.

```
>>> cat = cat.reset_index()                                                                                            
>>> cat                                                                                                                
    ID  Dec  Nov  Oct
0  XXX  4.0  1.0  NaN
1  YYY  8.0  3.0  NaN
2  ZZZ  4.0  1.0  NaN
3  AAA  1.0  7.0  9.0
4  BBB  0.0  NaN  2.0
5  YYY  5.0  5.0  0.0
```

I did this such that there is a column with the name `'ID'` by which I can group the other values. `groupby('ID', sort=False)` creates groups of rows sharing the same value in the `'ID'` column (and `sort=False` ensures that the rows in the final result are not sorted to match your output).

We can check the group sizes like this:

```
>>> cat.groupby('ID', sort=False).size()                                                                               
ID
XXX    1
YYY    2
ZZZ    1
AAA    1
BBB    1
dtype: int64
```

As you can see we only have one group of size two because the `'YYY'` ID is the only duplicated one.

`sum(min_count=1)` works like this: the values in each group are summed up with respect to their column. The parameter `min_count=1` ensures that a series of all `NaN` values results in `NaN` when summed up.

```
>>> cat.groupby('ID', sort=False).sum(min_count=1)                                                      
      Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                 
XXX   4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY  13.0  8.0  0.0
ZZZ   4.0  1.0  NaN
AAA   1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB   0.0  NaN  2.0
```

Demo for `min_count`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])                                                                                    
>>> s                                                                                                                  
0   NaN
1   NaN
dtype: float64
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> s.sum()                                                                                                            
0.0
>>> s.sum(min_count=1)                                                                                                 
nan
>>> s[0] = 1                                                                                                           
>>> s                                                                                                                  
0    1.0
1    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> s.sum()                                                                                                            
1.0
>>> s.sum(min_count=1)                                                                                                 
1.0
>>> s.sum(min_count=2)                                                                                                 
nan
```

Comment: I understood it the same way and just deleted my comment draft. Clean way of doing it!

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation for the downvote such that I can improve my `pandas` skills.

Comment: Hi! This looks like the cleaner of the two solutions, and seems to be much more efficient with the large dataset. Thanks.    ------ edit: not sure who/what the downvote was for. This seems the best

Comment: Is it possible to give a quick explanation about what the line is doing? I've never used `reset_index` / `groupby` / `apply` - could just read the documentation though! ha

Comment: @ChrisBrowne is the explanation ok?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to insert those values which only reside in one dataframe afterwards at those indices where the result of the sum is NaN:

```
result = df1 + df2

Month   Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                   
AAA     NaN  NaN  NaN
BBB     NaN  NaN  NaN
XXX     NaN  NaN  NaN
YYY    13.0  8.0  NaN
ZZZ     NaN  NaN  NaN

result = result.where(~result.isna(), df1)

Month   Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                   
AAA     NaN  NaN  NaN
BBB     NaN  NaN  NaN
XXX     4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY    13.0  8.0  NaN
ZZZ     4.0  1.0  NaN

result = result.where(~result.isna(), df2)

Month   Dec  Nov  Oct
ID                   
AAA     1.0  7.0  9.0
BBB     0.0  NaN  2.0
XXX     4.0  1.0  NaN
YYY    13.0  8.0  0.0
ZZZ     4.0  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This is a good solution, and better than mine. It still requires looping through each df (700+ from the big data set) tho, so maybe @timgeb 's solution is neater

Comment: can you see a good solution with having a list of loads of dfs? The inefficient way I can see is to merge two-by-two up a pyramid, e.g.

`df1_2` : (`df1` and `df2`), 
`df3_4` : (`df1_2` and `df3_4`), 
`df1_2_3_4` : (`df3` and `df4`)

which, over 700, might be slow

Comment: No, not really - I played around with sth like `result.where(~result.isna(), df1.merge(df2, how='outer'))` but it didn't work yet. And - as you already mentoined, too - @timgeb's solution might be better. However, they have to iterate through your bunch of over 700 dataframes, too, but at least it's only a one-liner per additional dataframe; my solution needs two commands each.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation @SpghttCd.

Answer (score 0):

This is late but I think that an easier solution exists:

`df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)`