# Sum to dataframes based on row and column

Tags: python, pandas

Given to Dataframes df_1

```
Code | Jan | Feb | Mar
a    | 1   | 2   | 1
b    | 3   | 4   | 3
```

and df_2

```
Code | Jan | Feb | Mar
a    | 1   | 1   | 2
c    | 7   | 0   | 0
```

I would like to sum these to tables based on the row and colum. So my result dataframe shoul look like this:

```
Code | Jan | Feb | Mar
a    | 2   | 3   | 3
b    | 3   | 4   | 3
c    | 7   | 0   | 0
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I can to this using a lot of for loops and if statements but this is very slow for large datasets.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723783/pandas-merge-data-frame-but-summing-overlapping-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: merge data frame but summing overlapping columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723783/pandas-merge-data-frame-but-summing-overlapping-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2]).groupby('Code', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  Code  Jan  Feb  Mar
0    a    2    3    3
1    b    3    4    3
2    c    7    0    0
```